# Trying to get results for promo codes GROUPED BY same promo id. (sql)

Tags: sql, oracle

This is the table structure:
[Table structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iZiE9.png)

One promo_id can have multiple code format for customers.
We have a few promo_ids for our win-back promotion at different months of the year.

I want to generate the number of codes grouped into the same promo_id, but at the same time showing an example.

Query I used:

```
select promo_id, code, count(code) from tableA
where code like 'HELLO%'
group by distinct(promo_id);
```

I get this error:

```
ORA-00979: not a GROUP BY expression
00979. 00000 -  "not a GROUP BY expression"
```

---

If I remove the code column from the query, it works.
But I thought of showing an example for each promo_id.

Can someone pls help?
Thanks!

Comment: _This is the table structure_ Actually it looks to me like sample data and not the table structure. Table structure includes column names and their data types. It may also include constraint details such as primary key column[s]. And is there some reason why you posted a screen image rather than writing or copy/pasting it?

Comment: show us table structure .

Answer (score 2):

As you want to show *an example*, then you don't really care about *which* example you show so - let it be the first one (`MIN`; could have been the last one with `MAX` or any other appropriate function), e.g.

```
SQL> with test (promo_id, code) as
  2    (select 123, 'HELLODAVEMar' from dual union all
  3     select 123,'HELLOSALLYMar' from dual union all
  4     select 554, 'TUESFREE' from dual union all
  5     select 666, 'HELLOTIMNov' from dual
  6    )
  7  select promo_id, min(code) code_example, count(*) cnt
  8  from test
  9  where code like 'HELLO%'
 10  group by promo_id;

  PROMO_ID CODE_EXAMPLE         CNT
---------- ------------- ----------
       123 HELLODAVEMar           2
       666 HELLOTIMNov            1

SQL>
```